# Joomla Fatal error: Call to undefined function wrap_with_span()

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla site at:
http://healthy-living.multi-web-service.co.uk/products

I am trying to set up a page using the module article newsflash adv to show a gallery of products. When I click to show the article title I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wrap_with_span() in
>   /home/multi123web246/public_html/healthy-living/templates/theme3021/html/mod_articles_news_adv/_folio.php
>   on line 111

If I don't show the article title, the product gallery does not show the the products.

Comment: Function _wrap_with_span_ doesn't exist.

Comment: Please expand; I am a total php novice. What shall i do?

Comment: I have removed the function so the php now looks like this:

Comment: echo ($item->title);

Comment: The page loads but the products dont show

Comment: Make a research yourself. Check where this function is defined, if not, define it.

Comment: Like i said im a php novice. Not to worry; solved the problem another way

Comment: It's an issue with [Module Articles - Newsflash (Advanced)](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/tm_art_news_adv/). No contact information, so the owner can't be told about the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Open modules/mod_articles_news_adv/tmpl/_item.php
Replace line 39 with:

```
<? PHP echo $item->title; ?>
```

(In your case /home/multi123web246/public_html/healthy-living/templates/theme3021/html/mod_articles_news_adv/_folio.php on line 111)

This problem appears when you choose "Show article title" and by default not linked to an article or set to "No".

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax I used and the error disappeared for me:

```html
<?php echo ($item->title); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `modules/mod_articles_news_adv/tmpl/_item.php`

Replace line 39 with:

```
<?php echo $item->title;?>
```

Put before this line without space and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as of January 2018, this extension hasn't been updated since 2014, hence no longer in tune with latest joomla versions (3.8 was the one to throw the errors for me)

Comment: I think so too, but I did not suceed in reaching 50 rep :) I have a lot of very good answers to questions no one asks !

Comment: OK, I dropped that comment in the "late answers" review queue, perhaps it is a helpful answer.

Comment: Indeed, it might save someone else being fooled by a downloading page not showing extension age.
Solution then being : don't install and get a better up to date plugin.